# vectorize a picture to pass into classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, computer-vision, image-classification

I followed this tutorial to create a simple image classification:

https://blog.hyperiondev.com/index.php/2019/02/18/machine-learning/

Before training, we vectorize the pictures in our dataset like this:

```
train_data = scipy.io.loadmat('extra_32x32.mat')
# extract the images and labels from the dictionary object
X = train_data['X']
y = train_data['y']

# example: view an image (e.g. 25) and print its corresponding label
img_index = 25
plt.imshow(X[:,:,:,img_index])
plt.show()
print(y[img_index])

X = X.reshape(X.shape[0]*X.shape[1]*X.shape[2],X.shape[3]).T
y = y.reshape(y.shape[0],)
X, y = shuffle(X, y, random_state=42)
```

Once we're done with the training, I want to upload another picture(which is not in the dataset) and pass it through the classifier to check whether it is predicted or not (along with it's accuracy score)

But how can I pass in a picture? I tried this:

```
jpgfile = Image.open("63.jpg") 
value = clf.predict(jpgfile)
```

and got an error that:

```
Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

So, how can I vectorize it accordingly since I don't have separate x,y values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reshape your image after loading :

```
jpgfile = Image.open("63.jpg") 
jpgfile = jpgfile.resize((32, 32) # resize image to 32*32
img_as_matrix = numpy.array(jpgfile)  # convert to numpy array
img_as_matrix = img_as_matrix.reshape(img_as_matrix.shape[0]*img_as_matrix.shape[1]*img_as_matrix.shape[2],1).T  # Reshape and transpose image as the train images
# Here the second dim is 1, since there is only 1 image instead of X.shape[3] images 

value = clf.predict(img_as_matrix)
```

Comment: I get an error that ```Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[212. 213. 217. ...  50.  50.  50.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.```

Comment: If I add ```img_as_matrix = img_as_matrix.reshape(-1,1) ```, I will get an error on the last line that ```Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 3072 and input n_features is 1```

Comment: Ok, it's a matter of shapes. Could you tell me the shape of X (after reshaping), and the shape of `numpy.array(jpgfile)` ?

Comment: ```X: (73257, 3072), np.array(jpgfile): (1024, 963, 3)```

Comment: So your image need to have shape (1,3072). I corrected my answer to make it so : can you check if it's working ?

Comment: Nope, not yet ```Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 3072 and input n_features is 2958336 ```

Comment: You also need to resize the input image to have the same size as original training images. I added a line to do so in the code. But be aware that the image is not the same aspect ratio (height/width) as training images, and that might affect model performance